# Tree Node Calculation - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query, recursive

I'd appreciate some help with something I am trying to achieve please.

The parts that my company make are built from sub assemblies and sub assemblies of sub assemblies.
This looks like:

```
             1
         /   \  \
        /     |   \
       2      3    7
      / \    / \
     4   5  4   6
```

Where 4 & 5 come together to make 2, 4 & 6 make 3, then assemblies 2, 3 & 7 make 1.

My table looks like this;

```
+------+-----+-------+----------+----------------+
| ROOT | SUB | LEVEL | LEADTIME | TOP LEVEL PART |
+------+-----+-------+----------+----------------+
|    1 |   1 |     0 |        4 |              1 |
|    1 |   2 |     1 |        2 |              1 |
|    1 |   3 |     1 |        5 |              1 |
|    1 |   7 |     1 |       20 |              1 |
|    2 |   4 |     1 |        4 |              1 |
|    2 |   5 |     1 |        1 |              1 |
|    3 |   4 |     2 |        4 |              1 |
|    3 |   6 |     2 |        5 |              1 |
+------+-----+-------+----------+----------------+
```

Each part has a lead time of how long it takes to make it. What I want to do is pass a top level part number and it calculate the overall lead time for the part.

Originally I thought I could just group by the Level and take the maximum lead time per level and add them together but that wouldn't be accurate. Level 1 Part 7 takes 20 days to make so we would be able to be making all of the other parts whilst 7 was being made. The calculation needs to be based on the part that consumes its parent (for want of a better phrase).

What I need to do is calculate the lead time for every route through the tree and add up the lead times as it goes. So I would like to return a table something like;

```
+----+----------------+-------------------------+------+------------+
| ID | Top Level Part | Parts Nodes Combination | Days | [BASED ON] |
+----+----------------+-------------------------+------+------------+
| 1  | 1              | 1 >> 2 >> 4             | 10   | 4 + 2 + 4  |
| 2  | 1              | 1 >> 2 >> 5             | 7    | 4 + 2 + 1  |
| 3  | 1              | 1 >> 3 >> 4             | 13   | 4 + 5 + 4  |
| 4  | 1              | 1 >> 3 >> 6             | 14   | 4 + 5 + 5  |
| 5  | 1              | 1 >> 7                  | 24   | 4 + 20     |
+----+----------------+-------------------------+------+------------+
```

I can then find the MAX of the days column which will tell me that the overall lead time for Part 1 is 24 days.

I really hope I've made my post understandable and all is formatted correctly. I've tried to read up on recursive SQL queries but I'm struggling to get my head around them. The most number of levels I am ever likely to have is 4 so I'd hope it wouldn't be too pc intensive. If so, I'd much rather be able pass all of my parts through, rather than doing them one part at a time (hence why I've got a top level part column in my table).

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any ID field and is there any PARENT_ID?

Comment: *Each part has a lead time of how long it takes to make it.* Looking your data I see that leadtime is referenced to SUBpart, not to part.

Comment: The SUB number is the part and the ROOT is the parent that it belongs to. The same sub part can belong to several different ROOTs but it will be referenced separately (same sub, different root).

Comment: Akina, yes - each sub (or sub assembly) part has a lead time, of how long it takes to make. I'm wanting to get a lead time for the top level part based on the lead times of all of the sub assembly parts but it is not linear, it is tree like so certain parts can be being made at the same time as others.

Comment: *I can then find the MAX of the days column which will tell me that the overall lead time for Part 1 is 24 days.* I doubt. Change leadtime for subpart 2 from 4 to 15. Your calculations will give 24 again. Whereas you need 2 pieces of subpart 2... or one piece may work twice in parallel?

Comment: @McNets Assume "ROOT"==Parent_ID and "SUB"==Child_ID.

Comment: @Akina I might be misunderstanding your comment (if so, apologies) but I only want to get the single 24 answer. Even though we need the sub item 2 twice, each of them will only take [n] days to make so, assuming infinite machines, the system will allow [n] days for each of them separately. I want to be able to say that from starting the first operation on the first part, to make the top level part, it will take 24 days as 24 days is the longest 'journey' between the nodes. All other parts will be made during this time too but none will take longer than the cumulative 24 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This solution also gets the intermediate nodes**

```
;WITH RecursiveCTE
AS
(
SELECT  [SUB] , 
        [SUB] as [Top Level Part],
        CAST([SUB] as varchar(255)) as [Parts Nodes Combination],
        0 AS [LEVEL],
        [LEADTIME]  as [Days],
        CAST([LEADTIME] as varchar(255)) as [BASED ON]
FROM dbo.Levels s1
WHERE [LEVEL] = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT  s1.SUB as [Top Level Part],
        RecursiveCTE.[Top Level Part],
        CAST(RecursiveCTE.[Parts Nodes Combination]+ ' >> ' + cast(s1.[SUB] as varchar(255)) as varchar(255)),
        RecursiveCTE.[LEVEL] + 1 as [LEVEL],
        RecursiveCTE.[Days] + s1.[LEADTIME] as [Days],
        CAST(RecursiveCTE.[BASED ON] + ' + ' + CAST(s1.[LEADTIME] as varchar(255))  as  varchar(255))
FROM dbo.Levels s1
INNER JOIN RecursiveCTE 
ON s1.[ROOT] = RecursiveCTE.[SUB]
WHERE s1.[LEVEL] > 0
)
SELECT * FROM RecursiveCTE
WHERE [LEVEL] != 0;
```

**Result**

```
SUB Top Level Part  Parts Nodes Combination LEVEL   Days    BASED ON
2       1               1 >> 2                  1       6       4 + 2
3       1               1 >> 3                  1       9       4 + 5
7       1               1 >> 7                  1       24      4 + 20
4       1               1 >> 3 >> 4             2       13      4 + 5 + 4
6       1               1 >> 3 >> 6             2       14      4 + 5 + 5
4       1               1 >> 2 >> 4             2       10      4 + 2 + 4
5       1               1 >> 2 >> 5             2       7       4 + 2 + 1
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5b89398a7537b373339090dfef76e2db)

**If you want to filter out the intermediate nodes:**

```
;WITH RecursiveCTE
AS
(
SELECT  [SUB] , 
        [SUB] as [Top Level Part],
        CAST([SUB] as varchar(255)) as [Parts Nodes Combination],
        0 AS [LEVEL],
        [LEADTIME]  as [Days],
        CAST([LEADTIME] as varchar(255)) as [BASED ON]
FROM dbo.Levels s1
WHERE [LEVEL] = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT  s1.SUB as [Top Level Part],
        RecursiveCTE.[Top Level Part],
        CAST(RecursiveCTE.[Parts Nodes Combination]+ ' >> ' + cast(s1.[SUB] as varchar(255)) as varchar(255)),
        RecursiveCTE.[LEVEL] + 1 as [LEVEL],
        RecursiveCTE.[Days] + s1.[LEADTIME] as [Days],
        CAST(RecursiveCTE.[BASED ON] + ' + ' + CAST(s1.[LEADTIME] as varchar(255))  as  varchar(255))
FROM dbo.Levels s1
INNER JOIN RecursiveCTE 
ON s1.[ROOT] = RecursiveCTE.[SUB]

WHERE s1.[LEVEL] > 0

)

SELECT * FROM RecursiveCTE
WHERE [LEVEL] != 0
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT * FROM
dbo.Levels s2
WHERE RecursiveCTE.SUB = s2.[ROOT])
;
```

**Result**

```
SUB Top Level Part  Parts Nodes Combination LEVEL   Days    BASED ON
7           1               1 >> 7           1      24      4 + 20
4           1               1 >> 3 >> 4      2      13      4 + 5 + 4
6           1               1 >> 3 >> 6      2      14      4 + 5 + 5
4           1               1 >> 2 >> 4      2      10      4 + 2 + 4
5           1               1 >> 2 >> 5      2      7       4 + 2 + 1
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9d409620f0722132ff2dd8386d3e82b7)

**Table & Data used**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Levels ([PARTID] INT,[ROOT] int,[SUB] int,[LEVEL] int, [LEADTIME] int,[TOP LEVEL PART] int);
--PartID added
INSERT INTO dbo.Levels
 ([PARTID], [ROOT] ,[SUB] ,[LEVEL] , [LEADTIME] ,[TOP LEVEL PART])

VALUES
(1,1 , 1 ,0 ,4 ,1 ),
(1,1 , 2 ,1 ,2 ,1 ),
(1,1 , 3 ,1 ,5 ,1 ),
(1,1 , 7 ,1 ,20 ,1 ),
(1,2 , 4 ,1 ,4 ,1 ),
(1,2 , 5 ,1 ,1 ,1 ),
(1,3 , 4 ,2 ,4 ,1 ),
(1,3 , 6 ,2 ,5 ,1 );
```

**Edit**

Op comments:

> I've noticed the data is repeating a lot (particularly on larger
>   assemblies)
>
> Basically I have Sub Router 1691, on top level router 1731. the Parts
>   node combination is 1731 -- 1727 -- 1691 and this repeats exactly the
>   same columns 8 times. Then, when it introduces another node (so 1731
>   -- 1727 -- 1691 -- 1682), this one repeats 168 times. This is the case all of the way through. It appears that any 3 level nodes repeat 8
>   times & any 4 level nodes 168 times.
>
> On a different one it repeats far fewer times. I'm wondering whether
>   it has something to do with the number of unique parts in the tree.
>
> I think I've figured it out! A single sub can appear on several
>   different top level parts. On the join to the recursiveCTE table I've
>   also added 'and RecursiveCTE.[Top Level Part] = s1.TopLevelRouter' and
>   I think it's done the trick.

Part of the query that needed to be changed:

```
 ...    
FROM dbo.Levels s1
INNER JOIN RecursiveCTE 
ON s1.[ROOT] = RecursiveCTE.[SUB]
and RecursiveCTE.[Top Level Part] = s1.TopLevelRouter
WHERE s1.[LEVEL] > 0
)
SELECT * FROM RecursiveCTE
WHERE [LEVEL] != 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Randi, will have a look at this today. The 'level' just represents how many nodes down the tree the part is. So a part could have multiple levels depending on which top level part it is belonging to. It might be on level 1 on one particular assembly but it could appear on level 3 on another.

Comment: @David Great! So the `level` does not matter for the calculation right? Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: I'm sorry it has taken so long to accept this solution. I've found that it works perfectly for what I need (I will just take the MAX value of the lead time per top level part). However, I've noticed the data is repeating a lot (particularly on larger assemblies).

Comment: @David not a problem :). Glad it helped. I am not sure on the data repeating part? As in the same ID's used or something?

Comment: It would be better if I could show you a screenshot. Basically I have Sub Router 1691, on top level router 1731. the Parts node combination is 1731 >> 1727 >> 1691 and this repeats exactly the same columns 8 times. Then, when it introduces another node (so 1731 >> 1727 >> 1691 >> 1682), this one repeats 168 times. This is the case all of the way through. It appears that any 3 level nodes repeat 8 times & any 4 level nodes 168 times.

Comment: On a different one it repeats far fewer times. I'm wondering whether it has something to do with the number of unique parts in the tree.

Comment: I think I've figured it out! A single sub can appear on several different top level parts. On the join to the recursiveCTE table I've also added 'and RecursiveCTE.[Top Level Part] = s1.TopLevelRouter' and I think it's done the trick. Thanks again for your help. This will be an extremely useful tool for me to use.

Comment: @David That is great, thanks for getting back to me. I added your comments & solution as an edit to the answer for future reference :).